# The multi-part identifier could not be bound (Joining a result set)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
alter procedure [dbo].[Test7]
    @Manufacturer nvarchar(20),
    @literatureType nvarchar(20), 
    @languageCode nvarchar(20),
    @modelCode nvarchar(20),
    @modelYear nvarchar(20)
as 
begin

select PartNum.PartNumber, ToolTip.EngText, ToolTip.FrenchText 
from
(
    SELECT  distinct PMYM.PartNumber 
    FROM ProductModelYearMapping PMYM 
    left outer join ProductMaster PM 
        on  PMYM.PartNumber=PM.PartNumber
    left outer join ProductLiteratureType PLT 
        on  PM.LiteratureType = PLT.Code 
    left outer join Model M 
        on PMYM.ModelCode = M.ModelCode 
) as PartNum
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        select PartNumber, EngText, FrenchText 
        from ToolTip
    ) as ToolTiP 
on PartNum.PartNumber = ToolTiP.PartNumber  
WHERE (

        (@Manufacturer IS NULL OR M.Manufacturer = @Manufacturer) AND
        (@literatureType IS NULL OR PM.LiteratureType = @literatureType) AND
            (@languageCode IS NULL OR PM.LanguageCode = @languageCode) AND 
            (@modelCode IS NULL OR PMYM.ModelCode = @modelCode) AND
            (@modelYear IS NULL OR PMYM.startyear <= @modelYear AND PMYM.endyear >= @modelYear)


        )

END
```

I am trying to join a table with a result set, also the result has to be filtered based on certain selections i make. That is the reason why i am using the where clause. But I seem to be getting this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your WHERE clause is referencing identifiers from inside your subquery.  You have to either move the WHERE to inside the subquery or you need to include those columns and change the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `WHERE` clause is referencing aliases from inside your subquery.  There are 2 ways to fix this.

One fix would be to move your `WHERE` clause to be inside your subquery where the alias exists:

```
select PartNum.PartNumber, ToolTip.EngText, ToolTip.FrenchText 
from
(
    SELECT distinct PMYM.PartNumber 
    FROM ProductModelYearMapping PMYM 
    left outer join ProductMaster PM 
        on  PMYM.PartNumber=PM.PartNumber
    left outer join ProductLiteratureType PLT 
        on  PM.LiteratureType = PLT.Code 
    left outer join Model M 
        on PMYM.ModelCode = M.ModelCode 
    WHERE
    (
        (@Manufacturer IS NULL OR M.Manufacturer = @Manufacturer) AND
        (@literatureType IS NULL OR PM.LiteratureType = @literatureType) AND
            (@languageCode IS NULL OR PM.LanguageCode = @languageCode) AND 
            (@modelCode IS NULL OR PMYM.ModelCode = @modelCode) AND
            (@modelYear IS NULL OR PMYM.startyear <= @modelYear AND PMYM.endyear >= @modelYear)
    )
) as PartNum
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        select PartNumber, EngText, FrenchText 
        from ToolTip
    ) as ToolTiP 
on PartNum.PartNumber = ToolTiP.PartNumber
```

Or you'd have to include those columns being used by the `WHERE` clause in your subquery and change the alias for each column similar to:

```
select PartNum.PartNumber, ToolTip.EngText, ToolTip.FrenchText 
from
(
    SELECT distinct PMYM.PartNumber,
        M.Manufacturer,
        PM.LiteratureType,
        PM.LanguageCode,
        PMYM.ModelCode,
        PMYM.startyear,
        PMYM.endyear
    FROM ProductModelYearMapping PMYM 
    left outer join ProductMaster PM 
        on  PMYM.PartNumber=PM.PartNumber
    left outer join ProductLiteratureType PLT 
        on  PM.LiteratureType = PLT.Code 
    left outer join Model M 
        on PMYM.ModelCode = M.ModelCode 
) as PartNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    select PartNumber, EngText, FrenchText 
    from ToolTip
) as ToolTiP 
    on PartNum.PartNumber = ToolTiP.PartNumber  
WHERE 
(
    (@Manufacturer IS NULL OR PartNum.Manufacturer = @Manufacturer) AND
    (@literatureType IS NULL OR PartNum.LiteratureType = @literatureType) AND
    (@languageCode IS NULL OR PartNum.LanguageCode = @languageCode) AND 
    (@modelCode IS NULL OR PartNum.ModelCode = @modelCode) AND
    (@modelYear IS NULL OR PartNum.startyear <= @modelYear AND PartNum.endyear >= @modelYear)
)
```